# невозможность стереть ОС в EEPROM Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi

Имеется Raspberry Pi с Cubian X (основа Debian) в EEPROM, которая не даёт её снести или загрузиться с SD-карты или флешки. Получить доступ к системе невозможно из-за особого графического интерфейса, расчитанного исключительно на роль антуражной части квеструма. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность сбросить EEPROM или воспользоваться загрузочной флешкой?

Comment: https://howchoo.com/g/ndhjmzhjngy/install-recover-raspberry-pi-4-bootloader ?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev пытался, не обращает внимания

Comment: "Получить доступ к системе невозможно из-за..." - доступ к системе должен быть! Иначе, как разрабочики с ней работают?! :-)  Возможны три варианта: RS232, SSH, Telnet.  По первому варианту - подключите преобразователь USB->RS232 и посмотрите, что валится на консоль во время загрузки.  По второму и третьему - знаете IP карточки? Тогда - nmap и долбить порты карточки. Вполне возможно, что они перенесли стандартные порты куда-то в другое место.

Comment: Если ничего не поможет - сделайте переходник с разъёма RS232 (который воткнёте в РС) на ноги GPIO-13 и 14 (это UART) который воткнёте в малинку.

Comment: @Sergey нет, доступа к системе правда нет, она не использует ethernet, уже было проверяно

Comment: @goodmice *она не использует ethernet* - ну тогда остаётся только RS232. Возьмите переходник "RS232 -> USB", USB воткните в Ваш писюк, а RS232 - в малинку. Включите питание на малинке и когда появится сообщение uBoot, нажмите "пробел". После этого сможете сделать с малинкой всё, о чём только мечтаете :-)

Comment: Если у Вас нет переходника, купите нечто вроде: https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/32968834880.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.19fd210e5thSmU&s=p&algo_pvid=0cdda111-31d1-40f4-abff-dfc3c1b17da0&algo_expid=0cdda111-31d1-40f4-abff-dfc3c1b17da0-3&btsid=f64c4704-fb2c-4899-b3bd-6f6ada5e03fc&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3,searchweb201603_52

Comment: @Sergey понял, спасибо, попробую

Comment: @goodmice Просматривал сегодня книжку "Raspberry Pi Cookbook
Simon Monk" (второе издание), так там в главе 2.6 есть подробное описание, что Вам нужно делать. Книжка (англ) есть в иНете. Первод есть в виде бумажной книги. Можно купить.